# using eloquent LENGTH() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel and I got stack in eloquent,

I am trying to search for names that match required length. I were expecting to be easy as :

```
users::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->where('name','LENGTH',5);
```

But it does not work :(

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `whereRaw` for this.

```
Users::whereRaw('LENGTH(name) = 5')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there's a native eloquent function for it. You may need to use `whereRaw()` instead:

```
users::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->whereRaw('LENGTH(name) > 5');
```